# How to access (shadowing) member variables in subclass from method in superclass?

Tags: java, subclass, member, shadowing

Let me know if someone does not understand the question. I tried my best to frame the question below.
I have a common method in parent class for generating pattern. For re usability, I thought to retain this method under parent class.

Inside the method, I use several variables. So I thought it is better to pass the object as the parameter to the method generatePattern. But since variables cannot be overridden, how can I use respective variables from these sub classes? Any other feature in java other than using subclass? Will "Generic types" as parameter work in such case?

```
class Parent {
    int var1;
    String[] values;

    void generatePattern(Parent obj1) {
        // This will not make use of respective values of 
        // subclass object that is passed I guess.
        newPattern(obj1.values, obj1.var1);    
    }
}

class AscendSubClass extends Parent {
    int var1 = 5;
    String[] values = {"S", "R"};
}

class DescendSubClass extends Parent {
    int var1 = 10;
    String[] values = {"N", "D"};
}
```

I may pass either AscendSubClass  or DescendSubClass above to generatePattern().
Inside this method, I need to use the variables var1, values and many other variables of subclasses. 
These variables are of same type and have same name, but the values are different and depends on the subclass. How can I refer these variables now in generatePattern() so that method does not change?
It is possible to achieve this by making variables as a parameters to methods or by if/else statements, but I have several variables to pass and it is big inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a getter method and override it in either subclass.

```
public int getVar() {
    return var1;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to define `getVar` and `getValues` as `protected abstract` methods in `Parent`.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now. But in "return var1" statement inside overridden subclass, is it not returning the var1 or parent? That means we are able to override variable in the case of getter method but not otherwise? I am confused little. following two statements are printing differently:  System.out.println("var1 = " + obj1.getter());
        System.out.println("Var1 printed without getter = " + obj1.var1);

Comment: The valued referenced in methods are always the ones defined in the class (Either inherited fields, or explicitly defined).